# Is it possible to use unique operator over a stream in jq

Tags: json, command-line, jq

The following code

```
for i in {1..10}; do 
    echo '{"key":'$(($RANDOM % 3))'}'
    sleep 1 
done | jq -n '[inputs]|unique'
```

would print (if they all had appear):

```
[
  {
    "key": 0
  },
  {
    "key": 1
  },
  {
    "key": 2
  }
]
```

The problem is that you need to wait 10s to see the result (`10` * `sleep 1`). Is there a stream version were as soon as a new element appears it would flush it to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a  [stream-oriented](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq) definition of "unique":

```
def unique(stream):
  foreach stream as $s ({};
     ($s|type) as $t
     | ($s|tostring) as $y
     | if .[$t][$y] then .emit = false
       else .emit = true | (.item = $s) | (.[$t][$y] = true)
       end;
     if .emit then .item else empty end );
```

You could use it with the -n command line option like so:

```
unique(inputs)
```

#### Programming Notes

The above stream-oriented version of "unique" does not entail a sort, and in that sense is more time-efficient than the built-in version.

The space required is linear in the number of distinct items.  If the items in the stream are known to be sorted (or arranged so that all items that are equal are adjacent), then `uniq` as defined below may be of interest.

#### uniq/1

The [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#remove-adjacent-matching-elements-from-a-list) gives this def for `uniq`, which behaves more like Linux `uniq`:

```
def uniq(s):
  foreach s as $x (null;
    if . == null or .emitted != $x then {emit: true, emitted: $x}
    else .emit = false
    end;
    if .emit then $x else empty end);
```